# so, $e=\sqrt[0]1$?

Tags: number-theory

or at least at the limit...

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E%281%2F%28x-1%29%29+from+x%3D0.5+to+2

(series expansion at x=1)

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+x%5E%281%2F%28x-1%29%29+

Does it tell anything about roots? (sorry, I can't put my finger on it, I have not enough experience in math)

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Any number exponent 0 = 1, so why e?

Answer (score 2):

What you've encountered is the fact that$$f(x):=x,\,g(x):=\frac{1}{x-1}\implies\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=1,\,\lim_{x\to1^+}g(x)=\infty,\,\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)^{g(x)}=e.$$(This is easy to prove by noting $f=1+\frac{1}{g}$.) But we cannot conclude $1^\infty=e$, because not *all* $f,\,g$ satisfying $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=1,\,\lim_{x\to1^+}g(x)=\infty$ obtain $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)^{g(x)}=e$. For example, multiplying the above choice of $g$ by $\ln c,\,c>0$ changes the limit to $c$. And, with a little work I'll leave as an exercise, you can get $0$ or $\infty$ as the limit instead. We say $1^\infty$ is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Comment: Thx! I didn't saw it as a form of indetermination